Startrow as a variable in Dataframe
I am trying to set the startrow of a df.to_excel() as a variable.
I have several df (9) that I would like to put in an excel one after another in the same excel sheet, but I will do this task every week and I do not know the size of the df, so I need to set the startrow as a variable.
In VBA it is something like this:
 startrow = startrow + len(df_3) + 4 #ADD 4 rows blanks

in Python the df.to_excel( .... , startrow = ... ) only allows numbers.
do you have an idea :)
thx

Isn't startrow a number?

it is indeed, default is 0 , but when I set startrow = startrow + len(df_3) + 4, it does not work. It keeps startrow = 0 for all my to_excel , so all my data are overwrite

Please explain better your issue, the question doesn't state your real problem (the data is overwritten).

You can achieve this in python the same way you use to in VBA. Try the following:
import pandas as pd

# Create some sample DataFrames
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7, 8, 9], 'B': [10, 11, 12]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [13, 14, 15], 'B': [16, 17, 18]})

# Initialize the start row
start_row = 0

# Create a new Excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

# Write each DataFrame to the same sheet, starting from the next available row
df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=start_row, index=False)
start_row += len(df_1) + 4  # Add 4 blank rows

df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=start_row, index=False)
start_row += len(df_2) + 4  # Add 4 blank rows

df_3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=start_row, index=False)

# Save the Excel file
writer.close()

This would save all your dfs to one sheet with 4 blank rows in between.

thank you Parman, it works perfectly, I forgot the startrow = startrow in the to_excel function
